# Unable to obtain cert via Amazon ACM for Cambodia TLD

Tags: amazon-route53, domain-name, tld, aws-acm

I registered for a Cambodia domain similar to example.kh. I've also added Route 53's NS to the registrar of example.kh. However, when I tried to obtain a cert from ACM, I'm getting the error "One or more domain names is not a valid public domain.". Any idea why is this happening?